# How to use on_delete CASCADE for some objects and ondelete DO_NOTHING for others in djando models

Tags: django, database, django-models, relational-database, django-model-field

I have a Django model that refers to itself as below:

```
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', ...)
```

I need to act in some situations as on_delete=models.CASCADE and in other situations as on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use on_delete=models.**SET_NULL**